# How to know that a request is from superagent?

Tags: javascript, superagent

I need to know the difference between `ajax` requests and `superagent` requests (I'm upgrading an old project from `ajax` to `superagent`).

Is there anything that shows that the request is used from `superagent`?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a technology. Any implementation of AJAX will likely use the underlying `XHR` object which is one of the below, depending on the browser:

- [ActiveXObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject)
- [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

superagent is a library that depends on one of the above APIs to work. In essence, both *ajax* and `superagent` are XHR requests. The receiving endpoint (server) can detect if the request was an XHR or not.

- HTTP header `User-Agent`: most libraries attach their library name and version instead of the browser user agent.
- HTTP Header `xml-request`, `sec-fetch-dest`, `sec-fetch-mode`, `sec-fetch-site`. Look for these.

Comment: So maybe it isn't possible to know the difference between `ajax` and `superagent` request?

Comment: No, superagent does not add any special headers to the request.